# SD card shield not working on 3.3v

Tags: esp8266

My SD shield works nicely on 5v supply, but does not detect SD card on 3.3v. Could someone explain the possible reason behind this? Could you also provide a solution for this?

I've worked with it on Arduino Uno. Now I want to use SD card directly with ESP-12E to read its contents using SPI [by doing something like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/esp8266/comments/48ib9g/connecting_a_sd_card_to_my_esp8266/). Since ESP8266 operates olny on 3.3v, I need SD card to work on this voltage.

I've used two separate SD card shields without any luck! Photos of the two shields and micro-SD card are attached.

[image: SDHC card shield-front]

[image: microSD card shield-front]

[image: microSD card shield-back]

[image: microSD card and adapter]

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your circuit is doing? The only info you provided was a few pictures of the readers. What are the wires connected to? 

Are you saying you connected 3.3V to the "3V3" pin and left the "5V" pin open?

Comment: How do you know it's the card reader and not your code that is at fault?

Comment: The circuitry is actually a pretty straight-forward SPI (MOSI-MOSI, MISO-MISO, SCK-SCK, CS-chipSelectPIN, GND-GND, VCC-VCC).
Yes, I connected 3.3V to the 3V3 pin and left the 5V pin open.

Comment: It's probably the fault of shield because it works when I supply 5V to it.

Comment: @AshishRanjan "VCC-VCC"? That's not helpful either. What is the other VCC? Realize that it's important to document what is going on. You're asking for help, it's best to give us as much info as possible.

Comment: @AshishRanjan That being said, 3.3V connected to the "3V3" pin *should* be sufficient. Try measuring the current being used on that pin, maybe that could show something interesting.

Comment: Sorry if I seem too vague. VCC could be anything from 3.3V to 5V. What I meant was, when I connect 5V to VCC, I am able to read the contents of SD card, but if I supply 3.3V to VCC, I'm not able to read or even detect the presence of the SD card.

Comment: @AshishRanjan I understand your issue, I do not understand what you connected to VCC! Where is the wire going!?

Comment: The VCC wire is going to the 5V of Arduino Uno (or the 3.3V). The GND wire is going to GND of Uno. Similarly
MOSI - pin 11
MISO - pin 12
CLK - pin 13
CS - pin 4

Comment: I believe the 3.3V rail also uses current from the 5V rail on arduous. Perhaps there is simply not enough current on the 3.3V rail.

Comment: I'll measure the current in 3.3V as well as the 5V line tomorrow, and let you know the results. Perhaps that would help us!

Answer (score 2):

I could not find any info on the full size SD card adaptor, but the microSD adaptor has a 3.3V ([LM1117](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf) or equivalent) regulator on it. It, therefore, needs a minimum of 4.5V to operate.

To run the adaptor from 3.3V, you would have to remove the regulator and solder in a piece of wire in its place.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, I'll try to run it by soldering a 3.3V wire to the output of AMS1117 tomorrow.

Comment: No need to remove the ams1117. Just adding a jumper wire between in an out will suffice.